# How to refer to a json file in Azure function

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I have a .net app which currently uses a json file stored locally on my machine.

I want to convert this app to an Azure Function App but I'm not sure where I can put my json file so that I can alter it in the future.

I am basically asking what is the equivalent in Azure.

```
var json = @"\DocumentExtractor\example.json";
```

Comment: my question here is if its a static file why dont you use something like blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are based on Windows OS, then azure function has a root directory: `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.

You can use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0

If you store a file in this root directory, it will actually be stored in the file share of the storage account specified when creating the function app.

Comment: Hi @bowman, thanks! So my equivalent would be `var json= @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\example.json";`?

Comment: @Greg Yes, you can.

Comment: @Greg You can also print current folder by code after deploy function app to azure.:)